# how do I properly write function signature to accept union-typed parameter?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to provide an API with a function that accepts a parameter that can be of type A or B. I am using `interfaces` to type the parameters. Those type do not share a single member. My attempts lead to compiler complaining about property x not present on type x.

```
export interface MyTypeA {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: boolean;
} 
export interface MyTypeB {
  prop3: number;
  prop4: string;
}

doSomething(param1: string, param2: MyTypeA | MyTypeB){
  switch(param1){
    case 'a':
    case 'b': {
      const cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyClassAComponent);
      const component = this.wrap.createComponent(cf);
      component.instance.prop1 = param2.prop1;
      component.instance.prop2 = param2.prop2;
      break;
    }
    case 'c': {
      const cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyClassBComponent);
      const component = this.wrap.createComponent(cf);
      component.instance.prop3 = param2.prop3;
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

I am not sure this can be done with `interface`s, I assume I might rather have to use `type`, but don't know how.

Comment: What is the implementation of `doSomething`like? What you have there is fine, but the implementation will need to use a type guard to figure out what's received.

Comment: I over-simplified my example which blurred my use case. I have updaed the signature here to show it's one of two params in the signature. I am trying to dynamically create instances of various classes (Angular components) based on `param1`, then supplying the instance with relevant `param2` properties. Now that I look at the code, I think I'd be better off creating separate methods. Some of the code will be repeated, but the code will gain readability. Still, I would be curious to know how to properly use union-types for future cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 3 possible solutions:

- Cast each single usage of `param2`.
- Use [Tagged Unions (aka discriminated unions or algebraic data types)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).
- Use [User Defined Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards).

I would go for Tagged Unions if it makes sense for you to combine `param1` and `param2`. Otherwise use User Defined Type Guards.

#### Cast each single usage of param2:

Too verbose in my opinion if you have to use it many times, but the most straight forward solution:

```
...

component.instance.prop1 = (param2 as MyTypeA).prop1;
component.instance.prop2 = (param2 as MyTypeA).prop2;

...
```

This solution will not generate additional code (the cast will be completelly removed from the generated code).

#### Use Tagged Unions (aka discriminated unions or algebraic data types):

You can combine `param1` and `param2` and convert your custom types to [tagged unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions):

```
export interface MyTypeA {
  param1: 'a' | 'b';
  prop1: string;
  prop2: boolean;
}

export interface MyTypeB {
  param1: 'c';
  prop3: number;
  prop4: string;
}

doSomething(param2: MyTypeA | MyTypeB) {
  switch(param2.param1) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b': {
      // The compiler knows param2 is of type MyTypeA, because its param1
      // property is either 'a' or 'b'.

      const cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyClassAComponent);
      const component = this.wrap.createComponent(cf);

      component.instance.prop1 = param2.prop1;
      component.instance.prop2 = param2.prop2;

      break;
    }

    case 'c': {
      // The compiler knows param2 is of type MyTypeB, because its param1
      // property is 'c'.

      const cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyClassBComponent);
      const component = this.wrap.createComponent(cf);

      component.instance.prop3 = param2.prop3;

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution will not generate additional code (the interfaces, including the tagged param, will not be present in the generated code).

#### Use User Defined Type Guards:

You can use [User Defined Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow down the type of `param2`:

```
export interface MyTypeA {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: boolean;
}

export interface MyTypeB {
  prop3: number;
  prop4: string;
}

function isA(arg: any): arg is MyTypeA {
    return arg.hasOwnProperty('prop1');
}

function isB(arg: any): arg is MyTypeB {
    return arg.hasOwnProperty('prop3');
}

doSomething(param1: string, param2: MyTypeA | MyTypeB) {
  switch(param1) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b': {
      if (!isA(param2)) return;

      // The compiler knows param2 is of type MyTypeA:

      const cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyClassAComponent);
      const component = this.wrap.createComponent(cf);

      component.instance.prop1 = param2.prop1;
      component.instance.prop2 = param2.prop2;

      break;
    }

    case 'c': {
      if (!isB(param2)) return;

      // The compiler knows param2 is of type MyTypeB:

      const cf = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyClassBComponent);
      const component = this.wrap.createComponent(cf);

      component.instance.prop3 = param2.prop3;

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Note this solution will generate additional code, as those `isA` and `isB` functions, as well as the calls to them, will be included in the generated code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I appreciate your effort in providing such a detailed answer. I definitely like Tagged Unions approach best. Feels the most TypeScript one.